# Is the behavior of the Bussard ramjet as described in Poul Anderson's novel Tau Zero accurate?

Tags: engines

The ramjet in the novel "Tau Zero" required a separate decelerator which, spoilers, breaks, and causes the ship to career endlessly through the universe. Is this accurate from a real-world engineering standpoint? Could they not simply have adjusted the collector to reduce the efficiency and tip the balance between thrust and drag?

Comment: Are you talking about the Poul Anderson novel?

Comment: Yeah...I cleaned up the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: The studies of the balance between thrust and drag are from 1985, the book is from 1970 and Bussard concept from 1960. Lots of things are known today that werent when Bussard proposed it and even later when the book was written.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking for the best current state of reality as we understand it, as opposed to the in universe science fiction.

Comment: Heppenheimer proved Bussard ramjets can't work, so don't worry about it.

Comment: If you'd like to expand on that inn an answer, @Organic Marble, that sounds like it would probably be a good candidate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes me sad because I grew up reading Niven's novels about ramscoops, but as early as 1978 T. A. Heppenheimer showed that the power required to compress protons enough to fuse exceeds the power that can be produced. Other reactions have been proposed but they have problems as well. There is a good writeup here: https://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=22274

Comment: So, in essence, the ramjet is a crappy solar sail 

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens: Yes. OTOH the idea isn't completely junk. It just needs to be adjusted for actual power requirements, with power deficit [supplemented externally](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/oh-my-god-particle-drive-performance).

Comment: I think the external supplementation pretty much kills worth of the idea. But there's still the hope of a different fusion method, or maybe the laser ionization jazz.