# What is the speed that we can reach using tsar bomba as a propellant?

Tags: propulsion, velocity

The idea of using an atomic bomb as a propellant was introduced in project orion, but it did not work out because of the interdiction of using the atomic bombs. So I decided to calculate the speed that can reach a bomb using tsar bomb, and what one of you to correct me if I have any errors.

Using $E=mc^2$, $m = 27 ton$, $c=300000000\frac{m}{s}$, $E = 27000 \cdot 300000000^2 = 2430000000000000 = 2.43 \cdot 10^{21} J$.

But now I am stuck in, how to calculate the speed?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to solve the problem -- how big an object are you accelerating with the bomb? -- but you're already on the wrong track. You're using the mass-energy equivalence formula, but hydrogen bombs don't have anything close to total conversion of mass to energy. (You also have the units wrong -- you need to use meters instead of km, so the e=mc^2 figure would be 2.43x10^21 joules). The actual yield of Tsar Bomba was about 210 petajoules, or 2.1x10^17J. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba

Comment: It depends on the mass of the spaceship what you want to accelerate with it, and on the effectivity of its drive.

Comment: I also imagine, if you manage to fill in all the variables, you'd get a lot less delta-v than you would expect. Orion used magazines full of bombs, and fired bomb after bomb to build up speed. A single bomb won't get you far. Making the bomb bigger means it'd be harder to not blow yourself up.

Comment: @RussellBorogove yes it's 210 petajoules because not all the bomb will be transformed to energy thank you ;)

Comment: @Saiboogu yes and there is a big problem and danger for the spaceship because of the heat emitted by the bomb and may be other radiation problem ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your calculation has the serious mistake: Not the whole tsar bomb became energy, only a very small part of its core. Its energy yield is known: $2.1 \cdot 10^{17} J$. On the mass-energy equivalence, it means a conversion of 22g of total mass converted to energy, from the 27tons of the bomb.

There is no technology to use Tsar Bomb as spaceship propulsion. There are [plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)) for nuclear propulsion using fissile micro pellets.

There is a missing input data in the question: the mass of this imaginary spaceship. Another missing input is the effectivity of the drive.

However, because only a very small part of the total fissile material converts to energy in any nuclear reaction, we can use the Newtonian mechanics to calculate it.

If we imagine a typical, around 30% effectivity of the termodynamical energy conversion, in the case of an 1000ton spaceship, the resulting speed is

$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \Rightarrow v=\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 2.1\cdot 10^{17} J}{10^6 kg}} \underline{\underline{\approx 355 \frac{km}{s}}}$.

Comment: thank you for your response but if you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)#Later_developments
it says that we can reach 12% speed of light can you explain this to me ?

Comment: @Taher The project Orion is theoretically possible, from the engineering it is on the border of impossibility: Investing some billions, something *might* come out. From the point of that antimatter is in the picture, the project becomes fairy tale. There is no effecient way to produce antimatter. The billions of \$s invested into antimatter production until now created lesser antimatter what could light a bulb for a minute.

Comment: @Taher i know that The project Orion is quite impossible ... but i wanted to know if we found a solution to that and we use a bomb h is it really possible to reach 12% of speed of light like it says in the wikipidia page can you give me which formula did they used to know what the speed that it can reach ?

Comment: @Taher $0.1c$ is reachable with a generational spaceship, using fusion fuel, if around 80% of the initial total mass of the ship is fuel. Btw, $0.1c$ is around the limit from where the interstellar medium, i.e. the around 1 hidrogen atom per cubic centimeter, becomes an issue (works as a radiation evaporating the wall of the spaceship). Furthermore, if the payload of the ship is around the mass of the ISS, the required total power of the fusion drive is around 1000 times higher as the total power production of the current Earth.

Comment: @Taher There is no way to get to 0.12c with fissile materials. The realistic is around what this calculation has shown: in the order of some hundreds km/s.

Comment: so you think that the only solution to make an interstellar travel is using antimatter which is too difficult and too expensive ?

Comment: @Taher First the ITER has to be built ($\approx$ 2020), then the commercial fusion energy production should spread ($\approx$ 2040), then the miniaturized fusion reactors should be developed ($\approx$ 2060), then we will have spaceships capable to some hundreds km/s.

Comment: @Taher There is no way to create antimatter effectively! In the equation, it looks quite well, you invest $9\cdot 10^{18} J$, and you get a half kg hydrogen and a half kilo antihydrogen. But the reality is that you shot a target with electrons or protons, invest $9 \cdot 10^{18}J$ into it, you get a mass of particles decaying in nanoseconds to anything, mainly to photons and neutrinos, and $\approx$ 0.001% of it is antiproton.

Comment: did you heard about the bussard ramjet ? may be it's solution

Comment: @Taher 1) You can vote for governments liking nuclear technology, it is particularly useful if you are in the U.S. 2) You can try to spread the science (and particularly, the nuclear technology) on the Internet 3) You can think on it, no one knows, where the really amazing developments will once come from 4) You can go to be a physicist if you are enough young for that. | This world shouldn't be always the same, maybe we will have luck and your grandchildren will establish a colony [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri_b).

Comment: I'am just 17 years old and i will plan to make a company like spacex but a goal to reach proxima Centauri hahahahah

Comment: @Taher The same "hahahahah", from the mouth of professional astronomers and physicists, had made your question closed and deleted, if I don't save it with my votes and answer. Now the world wants your votes. Never forget what I said [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27600/what-is-the-speed-that-we-can-reach-using-tsar-bomba-as-a-propellant/27601#comment82322_27601)! Never forget it in your entire life! Become a physicist or an engineer!

Comment: @Taher The bussard ramjet could work, but it is **very** hard. Don't forget: the interstellar medium has $\approx$ **1** hydrogen atom per cubic centimeter.

Comment: Project Orion didn't use micropellets. It used bombs in the 0.1-0.3 kt range.

Comment: Bussard ramjets probably won't work https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22107/is-the-behavior-of-the-bussard-ramjet-as-described-in-poul-andersons-novel-tau